# When add a new folder in the tree view control in C#

Tags: c#

I have Tree view control in my project. And i want to add a folder, it is adding but problem is this it is not editable or not set the focus of cursor at the time of adding the folder because i want to rename my folder.

Plz reply soon........
Thanks in advance..........

Answer (score 1):

I think u r need this...

Find Treeview Property 
`LabelEdit` and set `'True'`

then by selecting any TreeNode just press F2 to edit TreeView Node Label.

when  you set it `'True'` use following code when you are adding node

```
TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode();            
treeView1.Nodes.Add(node1);            
treeView1.Nodes[node2.Index].BeginEdit();
```

---

dnt forget to vote me...

Comment: it is already set. Plz see any example on window when u add the new folder then the cursor is blinking for demanding a new name. How I can do this in my project. So I want to know this.